# Handling Bitmaps wit help of picasso

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I have a webview in my app which loads some data based on user's input. 
I have a list view to show history of data loaded in webview.
Every time user enters new data, I capture weview into a Bitmap in following way

```
    Picture picture = view.capturePicture();
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

And add it to my listAdapter , In getView method of my adapter I set this bitmap on list's image with following code.

```
   myImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

When list size reached to a certain limit say 10, I delete old items and maximum size of listView is 10

If I had links for images then I could have used following call to load image 
Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg").into(imageView);
But I have bitmaps , How can use picasso to cache these bitmaps.
Also is there some better way to handle this scenario

Edit: 
My webview loads some maths equations. When user want to load new equation, I want to capture old equation from webview in Bitmap and show it in listView. How would i do that with Picasso. I know how to do it when i have weblink of images but I have Bitmaps in my case

Comment: with picaso you can tell it where to render http://square.github.io/picasso/  use the 'into()'. It´s fire and forget.

Comment: BTW you don´t need to preload the images, they will show up as needed or done downloading

Comment: My webview loads some maths equations. When user want to load new equation, I want to capture old equation from webview in Bitmap and show it in listView. How would i do that with Picasso. I know how to do it when i have weblink of images but I have Bitmaps in my case

Comment: no way on getting the url for the image?